# How to create a teaser of a product

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to create a product catalog in drupal 8 commerce 2.

I have some products created, I also created a database index and in the view (Home>Administration>Structure>Views) I want to show 'rendered entity'(product teaser) instead of fields, because the variation field contains image, color, size... and I just want to display image, title and price in the catalog.

I tryed creating a new content type with a field 'Remote ID' but I have an error enabling this field, PluginNotFoundException, and I didn't found any solution.

So, I don't know how to create a teaser for a product without create a content type (or fixing the PluginNotFoundException).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render individual fields from the variation, setting up a relationship in the View Advanced Section: Product uses variations.

After the relationship is set, then you can select what fields you need to display, filter or order the view results.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do with the **Commerce Quick Purchase** module. Just add any number of *Quickly add any product to cart* blocks and set the inline or your custom template to display a variation in the block. See more:
https://github.com/drugan/commerce_quick_purchase#inline-template